# Where do I find a custom function in a wordpress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress

Where can i find the function "premiumpress_header_inside" in Coupons Wordpress theme? 
I would like to make some change in this function. 
DO you any body know that in which PHP file it is located?

Answer (score 1):

All theme functions are stored in the file called functions.php inside the theme's folder.

Navigate to wp-content/themes in your wordpress installation, open the folder for 'Coupons' and then open the functions.php file.

You will then be able to search for the function 'premiumpress_header_inside' and make modifications.